# Call of array splitting functions requires call to .into()

Tags: arrays, rust

I am prototyping a function to split generic arrays using the nightly compiler:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs, const_refs_to_cell)]

pub const fn array_split<T, const AMOUNT: usize, const SIZE: usize>(
    array: [T; AMOUNT * SIZE],
) -> [[T; SIZE]; AMOUNT]
where
    T: Copy,
{
    unsafe { *array.as_ptr().cast::<[[T; SIZE]; AMOUNT]>() }
}
```

```rust
use array_split::array_split;

fn main() {
    let array: [u8; 4] = [0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x42];
    let [a, b]: [[u8; 2]; 2] = array_split(array);
    println!("a = {a:?}");
    println!("b = {b:?}");
}
```

However, this results in a compiler error:

```rust
   Compiling array_split v0.1.0 (C:\Users\Neumann\array_split)
warning: the feature `generic_const_exprs` is incomplete and may not be safe to use and/or cause compiler crashes                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 --> src\lib.rs:1:12
  |
1 | #![feature(generic_const_exprs, const_refs_to_cell)]
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: see issue #76560 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560> for more information
  = note: `#[warn(incomplete_features)]` on by default

warning: `array_split` (lib) generated 1 warning                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
error[E0308]: mismatched types                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 --> src\main.rs:5:44
  |
5 |     let [a, b]: [[u8; 2]; 2] = array_split(array);
  |                                ----------- ^^^^^ expected `array_split::::array_split::{constant#0}`, found `4`
  |                                |
  |                                arguments to this function are incorrect
  |
  = note: expected array `[u8; array_split::::array_split::{constant#0}]`
             found array `[u8; 4]`
note: function defined here
 --> C:\Users\Neumann\array_split\src\lib.rs:3:14
  |
3 | pub const fn array_split<T, const AMOUNT: usize, const SIZE: usize>(
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^
help: call `Into::into` on this expression to convert `[u8; 4]` into `[u8; array_split::::array_split::{constant#0}]`
  |
5 |     let [a, b]: [[u8; 2]; 2] = array_split(array.into());
  |                                                 +++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `array_split` (bin "array_split") due to previous error
```

Adhering to the compiler's advise, I added the call to `.into()`, which succeeds:

```rust
use array_split::array_split;

fn main() {
    let array: [u8; 4] = [0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x42];
    let [a, b]: [[u8; 2]; 2] = array_split(array.into());
    println!("a = {a:?}");
    println!("b = {b:?}");
}
```

```
warning: the feature `generic_const_exprs` is incomplete and may not be safe to use and/or cause compiler crashes
 --> src\lib.rs:1:12
  |
1 | #![feature(generic_const_exprs, const_refs_to_cell)]
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: see issue #76560 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560> for more information
  = note: `#[warn(incomplete_features)]` on by default

warning: `array_split` (lib) generated 1 warning
   Compiling array_split v0.1.0 (C:\Users\Neumann\array_split)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.81s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     Running `target\debug\array_split.exe`
a = [171, 205]
b = [239, 66]
```

Now I want to understand why this is necessary.
Why can't the compiler just evaluate that `2 * 2 = 4` and thus that the passed array is of type `[T; 4]`?

Comment: I'd say it's because _"the feature `generic_const_exprs` is incomplete"_ as pointed out by the compiler warning.

Comment: Maybe. It still begs the question, why the type conversion is necessary and where the respective `Into` or `From` implementation that is invoked there, can be found.

Comment: Note that [it works without `into` in the playground today](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=72dffe935d9a6f3418ee21fe555b96fb)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I just updated my local toolchain to `info: latest update on 2023-10-22, rust version 1.75.0-nightly (1c05d50c8 2023-10-21)`, but the issue persists here. I guess that's the drawback when working with the nightly branch.